# You have 1 unapplied migration(s)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am not able to search and migrate that 1 unapplied migration.

Please help me out

Comment: run this command, **`python manage.py migrate`**

Answer (score 1):

run this `"./manage.py makemigrations"` again and migrate again.

```
"./manage.py migrate"
```

Comment: vishnu@vishdino:~/Dinho/firstproj/firstapp$ python3 manage.py migrate 
python3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Already i did manage.py makemigrations, but when i try to migrate my app i getting this error

Comment: can you delete all your migrations file and run all the commends again(migrate again).

Comment: no its not working, i deleted and started my project from first

Answer (score 0):

First check migrations list

```
python manage.py showmigrations --list
```

In either case, there will be an [X] to show which migrations have been applied.

If you have unapplied migrations the run the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations    
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `python manage.py migrate`
If it doesn't work... then delete all files from migrations folder except **init**.py the go to database and find migrations table, delete all entries. Then again run `python manage.py migrate`